# Rust: how to make a separate reference to an item, which is already in a container?

Tags: rust, containers, shared-ptr

My server is handling approximately 50-100 clients, which connect with websocket, I'm using the [simple_websockets](https://docs.rs/simple-websockets/latest/simple_websockets/) library.

Clients can connect any time, and also they disconnect randomly. When a client connects, it gets a `u64` identifier from *simple_websockets*, I use this ID as the key for my container, which looks like:

```
pub type ClientList = Arc<RwLock<HashMap<u64, Client>>>;
```

I have a suspect, that it's not optimal, I'm not sure, maybe I'm wrong, but if I get a `Client` from it, it will be locked until the scope ends, in the example, `process_stuff()` finishes.

```
// self.clients: ClientList (defined elsewhere)
let mut hash_map = self.clients.write().unwrap();
let client: &mut Client = hash_map.get_mut(&client_id).unwrap();
client.process_stuff();
```

One of the clients is a special one. It is not connected when the server starts, it will connect just as other clients, the server will detect whether it's the special client or not. It should be put into the container as well, because it must behave as other clients, it has only a few special tasks. Also, there should be a quick access to it, e.g. a dedicated pointer. I would avoid pointer by storing its ID only, and pick it from the container every time, but it would be slow.

I can't use a simple pointer, because the special client is not present from the server's startup, it must be wrapped into `Option` or similar. This is the point, where my question comes: **what type of pointer should I use** for the special client, maybe I need to modify my container to be able to point to the same object from two pointers (a dedicated and the one in the container)?

Comment: One option is to wrap the client in `Arc` and store `Arc` to it.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then I need to wrap clients in the container to Arc as well, to be able to point to the same client, is it correct?

Comment: Maybe it's not possible to use the Client from the container without locking the container, the actual Client being processed must be kept in the container. Oh, Rust, I had no such problems with C/C++, but the sad truth is, that Rust has always right, I can't just drop out an element from a container while it's in use.

Comment: If you never change the element inside the container, you can use `Arc`. But yes, you will need to wrap the other clients as well.

Comment: Just done exactly this way.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the container part. It looks "too nested", but this is the truth.

```
pub type SharedClient = Arc<RwLock<Client>>;
pub type SharedClientList = Arc<RwLock<HashMap<u64, SharedClient>>>;
```

Plus reward: I can now get a `Client` both write/mutable and read/immutable, depending on if the program, who picked it from the container, should change it.

*Comment: high five to Rust for this, probably I've been never would use different access from a container, if I'm not forced to.*

Edit: the special client is also must be protected by lock, as it get its value during the operation, when potentially multiple clients may set it. It will never happened, but only because the clients' behaviour, there's no hard guarantee for that.

```
special_client: Arc<RwLock<Option<SharedClient>>>,
```

It will be used once under *write* lock, then always with *read* lock.

Please, comment, if I'm doing the wrong way.